# After initial setup does Xbox One controller via bluetooth connect automatically?

Tags: pc, controllers

Long question, sorry. I'm thinking about upgrading my wireless 360 controller (via adapter) to a Xbox One S (via bluetooth) for my PC. Currently when I hit the 'guide' button it turns on and connects to the PC.

Does this also happen after I have the Xbox One S (via bluetooth) setup? To put it another way, ***after I have my new Xbox One S connected via bluetooth and turn the controller off, will the controller turn on and automatically connect to my PC***? Really don't want to have to buy the adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you are looking for is **yes**. But you have to be careful, once set up, if you shut off then on the controller, it will connect automatically, except if you connect your controller via usb cable to another machine. You'll need to set it up again. On Windows 10, for it to work properly I personally had to use the *add a bluetooth compenent* feature.